# Factor into primes (=irreducibles): $\ 2+25\sqrt{-1} \in \mathbb{Z} [\sqrt{-1}] $?

Tags: number-theory

How can I factor below into primes, thank you!

$\ 2+25\sqrt{-1} \in \mathbb{Z} [\sqrt{-1}] $

Comment: Factor the norm of that element.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know about primality tests in the Gaussian integers?  (What's the norm of $2+25i$?)

Comment: See [What's a nice method to factor gaussian integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269810/whats-a-nice-method-to-factor-gaussian-integers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the square of the modulus of $2+25i$ is $2^2+25^2=629= 17 \times 37$. Now
\begin{eqnarray*}
2+25i=(a+bi)(c+di)
\end{eqnarray*}
where $a^2+b^2=17$ and $c^2+d^2=37$ ... can you get values for $a,b,c,d$ that work ?

> $(1+4i)(6+i)$.